# Checking for content in Django request.POST

Tags: django, forms, data-processing

I am accepting data via request.POST like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
    l = Location() 
    data = l.getGeoPoints(request.POST) 
    appid = settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY 

    return render_to_response('map.html',  
                               {'data': data, 'appid': appid}, 
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It accepts data from a bunch of text input boxes called **form-0-location** all the way up to **form-5-location**.

What I want to add in is a check to make sure that request.POST contains data in any of those input fields.  I think my problem is that I do not know the correct terminology for describing this in Django.

I know how to do it in PHP: look inside $_POST for at least one of those fields to not be empty, but I can't seem to find the right answer via searching for google.

If I don't find any data in those input fields, I want to redirect the user back to the main page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you thought about using [Django's Forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)?? You can mark fields as "required" when defining a form and Django will take care of validating if said fields have data in them upon submission. They also do other kinds of validation.

Comment: That's a good suggestion! Maybe look into ModelForms on djangoproject.com

Answer (score 6):

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST:
       # Process request
```

request.POST will be false if the request does not contain any data.

Comment: Note: falsy, not 'False'.  Like an empty dict or list, it evaluates to non-True.

Answer (score 4):

With Django request objects, the POST data is stored like a dictionary, so if you know the keys in the dictionary, you can search for them and check if they're empty or not. Check out these two links for more detail:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#attributes
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects

And, for example, when you have your request object, and you know you have a key/var called 'form-0-location', you could do:

```
if request.POST.get('form-0-location'):
    print 'field is not None >> %s' % request.POST.get('form-0-location'')
```

Comment: Ad if you don't know keys, how do you get them all? Loop over what?

Answer (score 0):

I second the suggestion to use Django Forms. Why not take advantage of Django Forms when you are using Django?

Design a quick form that matches the fields you currently have on the page. Load the form with `request.POST` data, and use `form.is_valid()` to determine whether the form is valid or not .

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST` returns a type of QueryDict (which extends the Dictionary superclass).

This means you can iterate through the keys in this dictionary (all the parameters in POST) and return false when you see one that is empty

(for key in `request.POST`):

```
if key k has invalid value (i.e. None or something else):
   return false
return true
```

Comment: OP wants to return False when all the fields are empty, not just one. Also, please format your answers better - the `for` statement should be within code, false and true should be `False` and `True`, and `if key has invalid code...` is pseudo code. Make sure to comment english sentences and provide equivalent code that works

Answer (score 0):

You could also try try  something like

```
if len(request.POST['data'])<1:
    do something if empty
else:
    do something if has data
```